# Using an arduino to emulate keyboard inputs

Tags: serial

I have a shapeoko 2, and have been wanting to create a jogging pendant for it for a while.  Currently GRBL (the G code interpreter for arduino) doesn't support jogging the machine with a pendant.  I was wondering if it was possible to emulate arrow key inputs on the keyboard through an arduino.

Comment: Pretend, for a moment, that we don't know what a "shapeoko 2" is, or even what jogging a machine with a pendant entails.  Instead focus on exactly what you want to achieve from the Arduino in a more generic form.

Comment: Your answers might lie in the Arduino reference pages: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardModifiers

Comment: Every arduino with programmable USB chip like Arduino Uno or Arduino Mega is capable of emulating any USB device.